# Unable to reference new C# class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

**Background**

I am working on a reasonably large legacy ASP.NET MVC solution.

Currently all of the code resides in just two projects (one containing model first C# generated code, the other containing the rest of the application).

**Problem**

I've added 2 projects to the solution - one for unit tests & one containing some code to be used as a service by the web application.

> When I reference the service project from the main project there's a yellow warning sign by the reference.

As I said this is a legacy project with code all over the place & I'm not sure why this is happening.

I've tried Googling for a solution but haven't been able to find anything that gives some clues to this problem...

**Note:** There are just two classes in the service project

Here's a picture of the warning:

[image: Reference warning]

Comment: you need to add the reference the using from the project or this could be a namespace issue.. do you know how to add a reference from an existing project..?

Comment: If you move mouse over a warning sign you should see the error message, could you share it with us? Maybe a new project targets to different .NET Framework version.

Comment: @MethodMan Maybe I wasn't clear: when I add I reference from the old project to the new service project (right click reference, add reference...) there seems to be a problem with it - there's a yellow warning sign next to the reference...

Comment: @PawelMaga nothing happens when I hover over the warning sign

Comment: @PawelMaga I've added a picture of it to my original post

Comment: ok so this could be that you are not navigating to the correct assembly and or dll can you show code in regards to how you have the using and namespaces setup.. also perhaps you are referencing from a lower level in regards to the project / solution can you show a screen show of the Solution explorer as well.. when you click on the actual project property what is the default namespace..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that both projects are set to the same version of the .NET Framework.

[image]

For example if your *Main project* targets to .NET Framework 4.0 and your *Services project* targets to .NET Framework 4.5.2, you can expect some compatibility issues.